# How to insert current timestamp value into kusto table using inline command

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer, adx

I am trying to insert current timestamp value into KUSTO table using now(), its not working as the inline command doesn't support functions or variables. Is there any way I can insert current timestamp value into KUSTO table.

Comment: can you please explain scenario what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline functions doesn't support functions and variables.
You can use `.set-or-append` command.

> If table doesn't exists then `.set-or-append` command will create a
> table and insert the data else it will append the data to the existing table.

**Sample Query**

```
.set-or-append  myTable <| print  data = todatetime(now())
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Can we insert multiple records with this command? like .set-or-append  myTable <| print  data = todatetime(now()), data = todatetime(ago(1d)).

Comment: @SwathiMiney, you can post your next requirement with a new Q's. Community will check and respond to that.